# Which Exception is thrown when a website is down?

Tags: java, exception, jsoup

I'm using jsoup to scrape data from websites. I want to know which exception will be thrown when the website from where I am scraping data is down. 
Is it `SocketException` or `NoHttpResponseException` or any other?
I read that `NoHttpResponseException` is thrown when the server receives the request but it failed to respond to it, is this correct?

Comment: I think it should be `RequestTimeoutException` as the client is unable to establish a connection within the given timeout

Comment: Point your program to a down website, and see by yourself. Here's one, for example: http://cocacola.com:8989/

Answer (score 1):

I tested our own website, after I take down the Tomcat I get the following `java.net.SocketTimeoutException`:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:563)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:540)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:227)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:216)
    at testing.Test.main(Test.java:19)
```

This is the code I used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://example/folder").validateTLSCertificates(false).timeout(1000).get();
        System.out.println(document);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`NoHttpResponseException` seems to be an apache httpclient exception (`org.apache.commons.httpclient.NoHttpResponseException`). Since Jsoup does has no apache dependencies, `SocketTimeoutException` will probably be the answer.